# If $X$ is a countable dense subset of the separable metric space $P$, then $P \setminus X$ is not separable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If the metric space $P$ is separable, then there exists a countable dense subset $X\subset P$.but if P is uncountable, Prove that $P \setminus X$ is not separable.

Comment: It's false. A metric space is separable if and only if it is second countable, and second countability is inherited by subspaces. So every subspace of a separable metric space is separable.

Comment: Your definition of Seprability is right, but my defination is also right it is written in my University prescribed book.

Comment: I haven't stated a definition of separability. Second countability and separability are different properties a space can have. All second countable spaces are separable, but not all separable spaces are second countable. However, all separable **metric spaces** are  second countable. And second countability is inherited by subspaces. Thus for **metric spaces**, separability is inherited by subspaces. (That's not generally the case, there are separable topological spaces that have non-separable subspaces. But such spaces aren't metrisable.)

Comment: @DanielFischer finally i got tge proof of my result. And that true

Comment: I don't understand what you say there. But just in case: If $P$ is a separable metric space, and $X$ any subset of $P$, then $P \setminus X$ is separable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assume $P-X$ is separable and then, by the prerequisits for the metric space you work with, you will get a contradiction. But I dont know what your metric space is! In general the assumption is wrong, think of $(\mathbb{Z},d)$ with any metric(for example the discrete metric).

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable. However, every subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is separable, including $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: thanks! I was to hasty and already edited it

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false. The reals, for example, have $\mathbb Q$ as a countable dense subset, however $\mathbb R - \mathbb Q$ is separable also. Consider the set $\mathbb Q + \pi = \{q + \pi \, |\, q \in \mathbb Q\}$. We still have that $\overline{\mathbb Q + \pi} = \mathbb R$, but this time we have that $\mathbb Q + \pi \subseteq \mathbb R - \mathbb Q$, thus forming a countable dense subset of $\mathbb R - \mathbb Q$. Therefore the irrationals are separable.